# My react-native's increment counter using useState suddenly stopped incrementing. None of the existing solutions I found worked

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state

My app has a component that consists of three buttons(only two are relevant though.) Yesterday I discovered that my setanimalNumber(animalNumber + 1) has stopped working. Animal number no longer increments.

```
const AnimalButton = ({remove, animalz, addtoList}) => {
    const [animalNumber, setanimalNumber] = useState(1)  
    return (
        <View style={styles.buttonGrouptrue} >
            <Button title={animalNumber + ' ' + animalz}
                onPress={() => remove(animalz)} 
                buttonStyle={styles.button} titleStyle={{color: 'black'}}
            />
            <View style={styles.directionalButtons}>
                          
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                    setanimalNumber(animalNumber, animalNumber + 1)
                    addtoList([animalz, animalNumber + 1])      
                    }}
                    style={styles.arrowButton} 
                    >
                    <Image
                        style={{  
                            marginLeft: 'auto',
                            marginRight: 'auto'
                        }}
                        source={require('../assets/arrow_up.png')}
                    ></Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>          
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

I have looked around throughout stack overflow and I have tried the following options.

```
setanimalNumber(animalNumber => animalNumber + 1)
setanimalNumber(animalNumber++)
setanimalNumber(animalnNumber, animalNumber + 1)

const test = (value) => {
let newValue = value + 1
setanimalNumber(newValue)
}
```

I know this is a common issue, but none of the solutions I found seemed to work. Any advice at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Of the following implementations, two are correct, and two are incorrect.

### Incorrect

- `setAnimalNumber(animalNumber, animalNumber + 1)`

  The `useState` state updater function takes only a single argument, either the value to update the state to ***or*** a callback function. This implementation only sets the state to the current value and ignores the second argument.
- `setAnimalNumber(animalNumber++)`

  This version *will technically* update the state value, but it mutated the state and won't trigger a rerender to see the new value.

### Correct

- ```
  const test = (value) => {
    let newValue = value + 1;
    setAnimalNumber(newValue);
  }
  ```

  This version will update the state, but doesn't take into account multiple enqueued state updates.

  Example:

  ```
  const [animalNumber, setAnimalNumber] = useState(1);

  ...

  test(animalNumber); // 1 + 1 -> 2
  test(animalNumber); // 1 + 1 -> 2
  test(animalNumber); // 1 + 1 -> 2
  ```

  The result of invoking `test(animalNumber);` three times is that only `was added to the`animalNumber` state.
- `setAnimalNumber(animalNumber => animalNumber + 1)`

  This is the correct way to enqueue a state update that depends on the value of the previous state.

  ```
  setAnimalNumber(animalNumber => animalNumber + 1); // 1 + 1 -> 2
  setAnimalNumber(animalNumber => animalNumber + 1); // 2 + 1 -> 3
  setAnimalNumber(animalNumber => animalNumber + 1); // 3 + 1 -> 4
  ```

  The result of invoking `setAnimalNumber(animalNumber => animalNumber + 1);` three times is that the previous state's value is used for each update.

  See [Functional Updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

## Solution

```
const AnimalButton = ({ remove, animalz, addtoList }) => {
  const [animalNumber, setAnimalNumber] = useState(1);

  return (
    <View style={styles.buttonGrouptrue}>
      <Button
        title={animalNumber + ' ' + animalz}
        onPress={() => remove(animalz)}
        buttonStyle={styles.button}
        titleStyle={{ color: 'black' }}
      />
      <View style={styles.directionalButtons}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            setAnimalNumber(number => number + 1); // <-- functional state update
            addtoList([animalz, animalNumber + 1]);
          }}
          style={styles.arrowButton}
        >
          <Image
            style={{
              marginLeft: 'auto',
              marginRight: 'auto'
            }}
            source={require('../assets/arrow_up.png')}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately the two solutions that you said are correct, don't actually work for me.  AnimalNumber doesn't change. I have verified this both with my Button title and a console.log. That is why I am confused.

Comment: @AlexanderSoudry I just don't think that's possible, I doubt React is broken. What, or how, are you validating the state update? Could you provide a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Your solution did work the problem is that the addtoList function is my actual application updates a state which then sets animalNumber back to 1 as seen here.
https://snack.expo.dev/@asoudry/animal-button

I added another component which also updates the state and like the addtoList function it resets animalNumber back to 1. Do you have any idea why it is doing that?

Comment: @AlexanderSoudry React state updates are processed asynchronously. Are you trying to use updated state in the `addtoList([animalz, animalNumber + 1]) ` call?

Comment: Because the updates are asynchrynous I didn't use the updated state and instead mimicked it with animalNumber + 1. animalNumber  + 1 equals the updated state in this case.

Comment: @AlexanderSoudry I think things were resetting because you weren't using a stable React key. Don't use `Math.random()` for React keys, it'll be a different key each render cycle and remount the component. Better to use a key value that is intrinsic to the data being mapped over. In this case, the `tag` value is likely sufficient. https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/animal-button

Comment: I just realized I never got back to you. I wanted to say thank you and that was it.